# Rails: Does a community standard exist on the proper indentation of options hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed many developers are very careful to keep their code lines to as few characters as possible. With that in mind, is one of these formats for options hashes more widely used than the others by the Rails community? This list is not all-inclusive, most likely.

**All one line:**

```
@user = User.create(:user, firstname: 'Larry', lastname: 'Jones', position: 'Beekeeper', favorite_movie: 'Wicker Man', favorite_team: 'Hornets')
```

**List after object:**

```
@user = User.create(:user, firstname:      'Larry', 
                           lastname:       'Jones', 
                           position:       'Beekeeper', 
                           favorite_movie: 'Wicker Man', 
                           favorite_team:  'Hornets')
```

**List under object:**

```
@user = User.create(:user, 
                    firstname:      'Larry', 
                    lastname:       'Jones', 
                    position:       'Beekeeper', 
                    favorite_movie: 'Wicker Man', 
                    favorite_team:  'Hornets')
```

**List with less indentation:**

```
@user = User.create(:user, 
          firstname:      'Larry', 
          lastname:       'Jones', 
          position:       'Beekeeper', 
          favorite_movie: 'Wicker Man', 
          favorite_team:  'Hornets')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install RuboCop, you can get your code linted. The lint includes indentation suggestions based on the Ruby Style Guide.

https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop

https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Your **List under object** is the way that RuboCop likes, "aligning the parameters of a method call if they span more than one line."
 https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-double-indent

```
# bad (double indent)
def send_mail(source)
  Mailer.deliver(
      to: 'bob@example.com',
      from: 'us@example.com',
      subject: 'Important message',
      body: source.text)
end

# good
def send_mail(source)
  Mailer.deliver(to: 'bob@example.com',
                 from: 'us@example.com',
                 subject: 'Important message',
                 body: source.text)
end

# good (normal indent)
def send_mail(source)
  Mailer.deliver(
    to: 'bob@example.com',
    from: 'us@example.com',
    subject: 'Important message',
    body: source.text
  )
end`
```

Comment: I like the way 'List under object' looks, except there's a slightly obsessive part of me that doesn't like having 'end' trailing way left underneath the hash, when it occurs. I suppose there are bigger issues in the world, though...

Comment: Agreed, your **List under object** style is the one preferred by the linked Ruby Style Guide and rubocop and is what I use on my hobby projects. You only make it this way if you can't fit the whole thing on one line. Of course, if you are working with others you should default to their style. Also, while I use 80 characters as my line's column limit, not everyone agrees with that and considers it a relic of low-res monitors. I prefer it because I often use a split-screen.

Comment: That final indent example looks nice. I'll follow that format.